# Calling $this->__construct() while cloning

Tags: php, constructor, clone

While cloning an object, I need to perform the same initializations that happen during the object construction.

Can I do this?

```php
public class MyClass {

    protected $myVar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myVar = 0
    }

    public function __clone()
    {  
        $this->__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see, it's easy enough to test

Comment: It works. But I wanted to know if this is the right way to reuse the constructor's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that just fine

```
class MyClass {

    protected $myVar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "constructing!\n";
        $this->myVar = 0;
    }

    public function __clone()
    {
         echo "cloning!\n";
         $this->__construct();
    }
}

$a = new MyClass();

$b = clone $a;
```

Output

```
constructing!
cloning!
constructing!
```